# dynamically add CSS with @font-face

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to dynamically change link of the css. In the newly loaded css (after changing paths) there are components like this:

```
    @font-face 
{
    font-family:"DejaVu_Serif";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    src:url(../fonts/DejaVu_Serif/font001.ttf);
}
```

but these fonts aren't loaded unfortunately, any ideas what can I do ?

Comment: Are you sure your fonts are there? And the correct MIME type has been returned by the server?

Comment: can you be a little more specific with your question? it makes no sense

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried creating the CSS file you wish to import using PHP, then loading it into your site with a quick jQuery call...

```
var css = jQuery("<link>");
css.attr({
  rel:  "stylesheet",
  type: "text/css",
  href: "YOUR-PHP-FILE"
});
$("head").append(css);
```

I used something similar on one of my previous PhoneGap projects where I wanted custom themes for each user... maybe this will work for you too.

Comment: Will not append it for a single time.